# Using multiprocessing with gunicorn in Flask application

Tags: python, multithreading, flask, multiprocessing, gunicorn

I made a basic flask application using Gunicorn with worker class gevent.  The issue I ran into was as follows.  If I had a basic flask app like this:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
import Queue
import random
from threading import Thread
import time

from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

def f(x):
    return random.randint(1, 6)

def thread_random(queue):
    time.sleep(random.random())
    queue.put(random.randint(1, 6))

def thread_roll():
    q = Queue.Queue()
    threads = []
    for _ in range(3):
        t = Thread(target=thread_random, args=(q, ))
        t.start()
        threads.append(t)
    for t in threads:
        t.join()

    dice_roll = sum([q.get() for _ in range(3)])
    return dice_roll

@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    # technique 1
    pool = Pool(processes=4)
    return 'roll is: %s \n' % sum(pool.map(f, range(3)))

    # technique 2
    return 'roll is: %s \n' % thread_roll()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

And I took two techniques at it, technique 1 will break gunicorn if I run it like:

`sudo gunicorn -b 0.0.0.0:8000 app:app --worker-class gevent`

but technique 2 won't.  I see this is because technique 1 relies on multiprocessing and technique 2 relies on threads, but I can't figure out why a gevent worker class doesn't allow for a pool?

Answer (score -4):

If you're using gevent. You should try using monkey_patch.

http://www.gevent.org/gevent.monkey.html

Comment: i'm not sure what this recommendation means

Comment: I'd recommend you review this https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: If youre using gevent you should have read the docs first before using it. It's the part were the most critical line that you should put it into your code before running any gevent/eventlet code. Monkey patch will turn low level calls to non-blocking. 

Technique 2 runs on python native threads. Without monkey patching it, it will be blocking. Monkey patching will turn low level calls of that thread calls to non-blocking. (RTMS)

Comment: As stated, I'm using gunicorn.  https://github.com/benoitc/gunicorn/blob/f69c17f8e29c88faf3d7c6cd13bec9abbdf78ba3/gunicorn/workers/ggevent.py#L65
A gevent worker calls monkey.patch_all() before it starts, so I'm not seeing a reason to add it to my code in addition to calling it when I run gunicorn for each worker.